# If $ab+bc+ca=1$ what is the minimum value of $10a^2+10b^2+c^2$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=1$. What is the minimum value of $10a^2+10b^2+c^2$?

I want to solve this problem without using Lagrange multipliers or calculus. I tried the following with some basic inequalities:

From AM-GM inequality $$5a^2+5b^2\geq10ab\\ 5b^2+\frac 12c^2\geq\sqrt{10}bc\\ \frac 12c^2+5a^2\geq\sqrt{10}ca$$
Summing them gives $$10a^2+10b^2+c^2\geq\sqrt{10}(\sqrt{10}ab+bc+ca)$$
But this doesn't help.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but try different coefficients. In particular, what is the equality case likely to be?

Comment: I don't understand the point of not using Lagrange multipliers when that's the obvious strategy. Are we trying to find some insight into Lagrange multipliers here that would otherwise be obfuscated by procedure?

Comment: @Jared Because it's a contest-math question, where calculus isn't needed and students are encouraged/suggested to find a non-calculus solution.

Comment: @Jared I'm commenting based on the context OP has provided (and my assumptions). I agree that Lagrange multipliers is a straightforward approach for those who know it well. $\quad $ As another consideration, what if you had to explain this to a 8 year old? Would you require them to learn about calculus and LM first, or show them an easier AM-GM approach? Of course, you may never care about such a scenario, just like you're not interested in contests.

Comment: @Jared I don't want a Lagrange multiplier solution because I don't know it as I'm a high schooler. Also as I am the asker of the question, I think I have the right to mention what kind of answer I need so that the answer is suitable for me.

Comment: I guess I missed the part where it was obvious this was a high-school level math contest question. I apologize if I insinuated LM is the "best" method (and thus should be preferred). The fact that it was called out specifically, suggested to me that OP had a knowledge of them and thus why I asked why not use them--that was clearly an incorrect assumption on my part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** If we additionally make the (reasonable, though not necessarily true) assumption that the minimum happens when $ a = b$, then reduce it to a 1 variable inequality and hence show that the minimum is 4 obtained at $ ( 1/3, 1/3, 4/3)$.
Note that we've not proven this is the minimum yet.

Use this to figure out what AM-GM's to create.
Modifying your approach, we have the following inequalities:

$a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab \longrightarrow$ This reinforces $a=b$ at the equality case.
$Xa^2 + 0.5c^2 \geq 2\sqrt{X/2}ac \longrightarrow$ What does the (assumed) equality case tell us about $X$?
$Yb^2 + 0.5c^2 \geq 2\sqrt{Y/2}bc \longrightarrow$ What does the (assumed) equality case tell us about $Y$?

From the equality case, we require

> $ X = 8$, $ Y = 8$.

Then, weight the inequalities to get

> $ 2a^2 + 2b^2 \geq 4ab $
>  $ 8 a^2 + 0.5 c^2 \geq 4 ac $
>  $ 8b^2 + 0.5c^2 \geq 4bc $
>  Summing them up gives:

$$ 10a^2 + 10b^2 + c^2 \geq 4(ab+bc+ca) = 4,$$

with equality when $ a = b = c/4, ab+bc+ca = 1$, IE $ ( 1/3, 1/3, 4/3)$.
(Thankfully, our initial assumption is true.)

---

I wanted to show you how to derive these inequalities (assuming that your stated approach could work). It isn't just "magic" or "by observation" or "by luck".
For the actual solution, you just need to write out the 3 AM-GM inequalities, sum them up, and verify the equality case.

Using this approach, try your hand at minimizing (say) $3a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2 $ given $ab+bc+ ca = 1$.
(Note: I've not actually done this, so I can't guarantee that the values will look nice.)

Comment: There is reasoning, how to find the minimum without assumption that the equality occurs for $a=b$. See my solution. This reasoning works also in the general.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Right. I wanted to stay within OP's approach (and without adding too many unknowns, hence the assumption $a=b$). EG My go-to for quadratic inequalities is to set up the matrix and calculate discriminants.

Comment: @CalvinLin If AM-GM (actually) works, then we can do it using the method of unknown coefficients: $p_1 a^2 + q_1b^2 \ge 2\sqrt{p_1q_1}ab, \quad p_2b^2 + q_2c^2 \ge 2\sqrt{p_2q_2}bc,\quad p_3c^2 + q_3a^2 \ge 2\sqrt{p_3q_3}ca$, and we require $p_1q_1 = p_2q_2 = p_3q_3$, $p_1 + q_3 = 10, q_1 + p_2 = 10, q_2 + p_3 = 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi Right, hence the "without adding too many unknowns", esp since I'm assuming that OP isn't familiar with it. What I'm doing is essentially a simplified version.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sometimes we might do it in such a way, for example, the following problem (and solution due to SBM@AoPS): Let $a, b \ge 0$. Prove that $a^2b^2 (a^2 + b^2 - 2) \ge (a + b)(ab - 1)$. We can split into three parts (AM-GM): ${a}^{2}b\le \frac25\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+\frac25\,a+\frac15\,b$, $a{b}^{2}\le\frac{1}{10}\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+\frac{3}{10}\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}+\frac{3}{5}\,b$, and $2\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}\le \frac12{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+{\dfrac {7}{10}}{a}^{2}{b}^
{4}+\frac35a+\frac15b$.

Comment: @RiverLi OMFG, I would have [tried to rearrange terms creatively](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#application-of-am-gm-on-terms-obtained-after-rearranging-creatively) but likely wouldn't have figured out those coefficients.  Thanks for sharing this question, let me see if I can solve it.

Comment: @RiverLi We have $ a^2b \leq \frac{2}{5} a^4 b^2 + \frac{2}{5} a + \frac{1}{5} b $ (which you stated), $ ab^2 \leq \frac{2}{5} a^2b^4 + \frac{2}{5} b + \frac{1}{5} a $, and $ 2a^2b^2 \leq \frac{3}{5} a^4b^2 + \frac{3}{5} a^2b^4 + \frac{2}{5} a + \frac{2}{5} b$. $\quad$  Do you know of a case where symmetric coefficients do not work?

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you mean $a^2 b \le f_1(a, b), ab^2\le f_2(a, b), 2a^2b^2 \le f_3(a, b)$ for some polynomial $f_i(a,b)$ with none symmetric coefficients?

Comment: @RiverLi I meant "Is there a symmetric inequality, where the method of unknown coefficients requires us to use non-symmetric coefficients?" If yes, why can't symmetric coefficients work out?   (IE I got to that solution by setting $ A a^4b^2 + B b^2a^4 + Ca + Db \geq a^2b, (1-A-B) (a^4 b^2 + a^2b^4) + (1-C-D)(a+b) \geq 2a^2b^2$)

Comment: @CalvinLin I think the author of the solution used software to find the coefficients. You asked a nice question. But I have no answer for it.

Answer (score 5):

Let $k$ be the minimal value.

Thus, $k>0$ and the inequality $$10a^2+10b^2+c^2\geq k(ab+ac+bc)$$ or $$c^2-k(a+b)c+10a^2+10b^2-kab\geq0$$ is true for any reals $a$,$b$ and $c$ (because after homogenization the condition $ab+ac+bc=1$ is not relevant already), which says $$k^2(a+b)^2-4(10a^2+10b^2-kab)\leq0,$$ which gives
$$(40-k^2)a^2-2(2k+k^2)ab+(40-k^2)b^2\geq0,$$ for which we need $40-k^2>0$ and $$(2k+k^2)^2-(40-k^2)^2\leq0$$ or $$(k+20)(k+5)(k-4)\leq0$$ or
$$0<k\leq4,$$ which gives that a maximal value of $k$, for which the inequality $$10a^2+10b^2+c^2\geq k(ab+ac+bc)$$ is true it's $4$.

The equality occurs for $a=b$ and $c=\frac{k(a+b)}{2}=4a$.

Id est, $$\min_{ab+ac+bc=1}(10a^2+10b^2+c^2)=4.$$

Comment: Side note: You might want to clarify why it's "true for any reals $a, b, c$", since the question is restricted to $ ab + bc + ca = 1$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin  I added. Thank you!

Comment: typo: $(40-k^2)a^2-2(2k-k^2)ab+(40-k^2)b^2\geq0$ should be $(40-k^2)a^2-2(2k+k^2)ab+(40-k^2)b^2\geq0$.

Comment: @River Li Thank you! I fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

By C-S
$$10a^2+10b^2+c^2=$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(8a^2+\frac{c^2}{2}+8b^2+\frac{c^2}{2}+2a^2+2b^2\right)\left(\frac{c^2}{2}+8a^2+\frac{c^2}{2}+8b^2+2b^2+2a^2\right)}\geq\sqrt{(2ac+2ac+2bc+2bc+2ab+2ab)^2}=\sqrt{16}=4.$$
The equality occurs, when
$$\left(2\sqrt2a,\frac{c}{\sqrt2},2\sqrt2b,\frac{c}{\sqrt2},\sqrt2a,\sqrt2b\right)||\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt2},2\sqrt2a,\frac{c}{\sqrt2},2\sqrt2b,\sqrt2b,\sqrt2a\right),$$ which gives $a=b=\frac{c}{4}$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 2):

Noting that
$$20 a^{2}+20 b^{2}+2 c^{2}-8(a b+b c+c a)=(2 a-2 b)^{2}+(4 b-c)^{2}+(4 a-c)^{2} \geqslant 0,
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\quad 2\left(10 a^{2}+10 b^{2}+c^{2}\right)\geqslant 8 \quad \Rightarrow \quad 10 a^{2}+10 b^{2}+c^{2} \geqslant 4
\end{aligned}
$$
The minimum value of $10 a^{2}+10 b^{2}+c^{2}$ is $4$, which is attained if and only if$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a=b \\
4 b=c \\
c=4 a
\end{array}\right.
 \Leftrightarrow 
a=b=\frac{1}{3} \text { and } c=\frac{4}{3}
$$